# Load component based on query param in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a state in a component as follow.

```js
.state('owner-details', {
            parent: 'app',
            url: '/vehical/sections/:sectionId/?custom_mode=preview',
            data: {
                authorities: ['owner'],
                pageTitle: "Owner Details"
            },
            views: {
                'content@': {
                    component: 'ownerDetails'
                },
                'breadcrumb@': {
                    component: 'breadcrumb'
                }
            },
            resolve: {
                
            }
        });
```

I want to load the component if the query param custom_mode equals to preview.

Is this possible in AngularJS? If so: how can I do this?

Comment: AngularJS or Angular?

Comment: @ChamilaMaddumage Angularjs